# Quality filter preventing including links to jsfiddle tricked by using backticks

Tags: bug, questions, quality-filter

I recently came across a question that had backticks enclosing the entire content, as you can see in this screenshot:

> [image: Published question]

The jsfiddle URL at the end is not a proper link, nor is it rendered as inline code, even though it is also wrapped in backticks. Its color is the same as the normal text.

When I tried to remove those backticks wrapped around the question body, the quality filter told me:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

> [image: Edited question showing error]

Fair enough. Removing the backticks surrounding the jsfiddle URL turns it into a link:

> [image: Edited question showing URL as link]

At simple sight, it looks that the way that the backticks were placed prevented that the URL were identified as an URL / link.

I think that the quality filter should not allow a question to start and end with backticks. What I mean is that the quality filter should not allowed the revision 1.

---

Revision 1 source

```
`I need to display the data from this spreadsheet in excel in table format. I managed to consume some data through the Google Sheet API, however, I cannot capture and display the data from all tabs in the spreadsheet. What's the best way to do this?

This my code example:

`https://jsfiddle.net/Lx3mk694/``
```

Comment: how did this even get posted? i can't get that past the new question wizard, regardless of what i do with code blocks.

Comment: @KevinB 1) Add a fancy title 2) Paste the first line in the first text box 3) paste the 2 and following links in the second text box, 4) etc., etc. (I added the source code of the revision 1 to this question)

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that the link has a special character at the start, rather than the entire question being surrounded in backticks. The markdown editor isn't matching any of the backticks together into code blocks.

For example:

> `https://stackoverflow.com`
>
> https://stackoverflow.com

And with a leading backtick:

> `` `https://stackoverflow.com ``
>
> `https://stackoverflow.com

And, specifically, as in the example given, the double backtick doesn't match with the first backtick, so is just rendered as text:

> ``` `https://stackoverflow.com`` ```
>
> `https://stackoverflow.com``

Finally, just for fun, you can do the same with other characters too:

> `$https://stackoverflow.com`
>
> $https://stackoverflow.com

SO doesn't think the URL is in a code block, it doesn't even think it's a URL. After all, what sort of URL begins with a backtick? Something should probably be done about this, it's a trivial enough way of circumventing that validation rule.